# After creating RAID 1 can't connect to server

Tags: raid

I have created RAID 1 array consisting of 2 devices(working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) :

```
mdadm --create /dev/md6 -l 1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda9 /dev/sdb6 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md6
mkdir /raid 
mdadm –detail –scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
update-initramfs -u
vim /etc/fstab  # next line is what I've put into the fstab file
/dev/md6    /raid       ext4        defaults    0  0
mount /raid
```

After the reboot I can't connect to my server(via ssh). 
Only when I boot into rescue mode and comment out fstab and mdadm.conf lines consisting info about md6, then I'm able to connect to my server.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md6
/dev/md6:
       Version : 1.2
 Creation Time : Sun Jan 26 14:52:22 2020
    Raid Level : raid1
    Array Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
 Used Dev Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
  Raid Devices : 2
 Total Devices : 2
   Persistence : Superblock is persistent

   Update Time : Sun Jan 26 17:06:17 2020
         State : clean 
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
 Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

          Name : popaja:6  (local to host popaja)
          UUID : 67d43386:09285115:0c33fcec:68fb2054
        Events : 17

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        9        0      active sync   /dev/sda9
   1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
```

This is how mdadm.conf looks like :

```
 # This configuration was auto-generated on Sat, 24 Nov 2018 16:01:31      +0000 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=e402909e:fd60a086:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=a0e2960f:72c3523c:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md5 UUID=d97cc04c:2812a744:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=e402909e:fd60a086:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=0.90 UUID=a0e2960f:72c3523c:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md5 metadata=0.90 UUID=d97cc04c:2812a744:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md6 metadata=1.2 name=popaja:6 UUID=67d43386:09285115:0c33fcec:68fb2054
```

As you can see I have more RAID devices and they have never bothered me. 
Am I missing something ?

### UPDATE :

I went to my server provider's page(control panel) and made a fresh installation, choosing /boot, /, /home on raid 1 arrays. Also I chose two more additional raid arrays as /raid and /raid1. 
What's weird that after installation everything works as expected but the trouble comes when I try to create raid arrays myself with mdadm command.

This is how everything looks right now :

```
vim /etc/fstab

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md1        /boot   ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md5        /home   ext4    defaults        1       2
/dev/md6        /raid   ext4    defaults        1       2
/dev/md7        /raid1  ext4    defaults        1       2
/dev/sda3       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb3       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
~                                                                    

vim /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

# This configuration was auto-generated on Sat, 24 Nov 2018 16:01:31 +0000 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=44642845:2ace7714:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=92b6b281:c860fcce:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md5 UUID=67bd76dc:3d620e68:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md6 UUID=5e9aacb7:13436f9e:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md7 UUID=36a9f6dc:2b8e82d8:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
~                                                                                                                                                     
~
```

I decided I'm not gonna mess around with RAIDs for the time being, as I don't need them. But it's a strange case.

Comment: Use the UUIDs in `/etc/fstab` as well for mounting.  Don't use `/dev/mdX` as that can change during reboots.  Get the UUIDs from running `sudo blkid` as this is not the same UUID from `mdadm.conf`.  Then the mount line in `/etc/fstab` would look something like `UUID=a50fd553-b143-4ad8-bdb1-2247d9349e86 /raid ext4 defaults 0 0` instead of `/dev/md6    /raid       ext4        defaults    0  0`

Comment: @Terrance tried it, hasn't worked either.
Thank you.
I've asked senior sys admin to look at it and he couldn't solve it :]

Comment: Why is it that in your question before the edit you have the `dump` and `pass` fields both with `0` on your line, but in your actual `fstab` file you have them as `1` and as `2`?  Really, they should be `0`.  On my system that I am running RAIDs on the only one that is not a `0` is the `pass` field on my `/` root mount.  And all my mount points use the UUIDs that I get from the `sudo blkid` command because leaving a simple USB drive in the system on a reboot can change mount `/dev` designations.

Comment: If you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab you will see that really all the the mounts in the `dump` field are `0`.  You can use `2` in the `pass` field on your RAIDs if you want, but that might slow down checks when they are performed.

Comment: @Terrance it's 1 and 2 because this is what I got when I received it with a fresh install. Remember, in my fresh install I also chose to make two more raid (1) arrays ? Well, this is how they were built - with 1 and 2 in fstab. I haven't touched there anything. And won't. I had enough. 
But thank you for pointing out about using UUID in fstab, I'll take it with me.